# handling transactions in code igniter spanning multiple model files

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I'm trying to implement transactions in code igniter.

The problem is My DML statements are in multiple model files.

And my Controller action looks like so:

```
//the following is inside a controller
public function myaction()
{
    transaction_start();
    first_model->setSomeData();
    second_model->setSomeData();
    third_model->setSomeData();
    transaction_complete();
}
```

I am working on a mysql database and i have made them tables in the involved models innodb as I understand that engine supports transaction.

The above code structure doesnt seem to work as i deliberate made the second model insert to fail.I expected the three inserts(1 in each of the setsomedata method of the three models) to all fail or all succeed. But that wasnt the case

Any ideas please?

Comment: its not working in what aspect , u mean the atomicity ?

Comment: yes the atomicity is not working...some insert statements succeeded while some failed...i expected all to succeed or all to fail since they three calls are wrapped in a transaction begin and end statement.

Comment: I'm still hoping that someone will be nice enough to show me how to achieve this...@user1537158

Comment: @oliverdejohnson I also have the same questions, did you get the answer?

Comment: @StonyZhang no i didnt....seem i might have to start a bounty on this question to generate interest

Answer (score 0):

To call a model in codeigniter theres a  load->model function

```
<?php
controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('FirstModel');
        $this->load->model('SecondModel');
    }
?>
```

and to use it in some action

```
<?php
//...
    public function index(){
        $this->FirstModel->getData();
        $this->SecondModel->getData();
    }
//...
?>
```

Comment: This has exactly nothing to do with op's question, which is about DB transactions spanning multiple models.

Comment: i did load the models properly...my problem is coordinating transactions when the actual DMLs is in multiple models(i.e classes).

Comment: Thanks all the same Abimael for trying to help. i'm still having this problem since last year!